# How to replace reactive value based on API response in Vue js 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I am trying to set the state of the checkbox based on the API response but I am not able to change its state.

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
    import { ref, toRefs, reactive, onMounted } from "vue";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { Check, Close } from "@element-plus/icons-vue";
    import Loading from "../Loading.vue";

    let state = reactive({
        options: {},
        errors: [],
        loading: true,
        enableQuickView: true, //  How to replace this value based on the API response?
    });

    let { loading, options, enableQuickView } = toRefs(state);

    let BASE_API_URL = 'http://wpvue.local/wp-json/quick_view_api/get_settings/';

    //  Doing API call to get the settings.
    let FetchOptions = () => {
        axios
            .get(BASE_API_URL + "get_options")
            .then((res) => {
                state.options = res.data.settings;
                console.log(res.data.settings);
                state.loading = false;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                state.errors = err;
            });
    };

    //  Invoke FetchOptions function.
    onMounted(() => {
        FetchOptions();
    });
</script>
<template>
    <Loading v-if="loading" />
    <form v-else id="xox-settings-form" class="xox-form" @submit.prevent>
        <h3 class="option-box-title">{{ options.general.section_label }}</h3>
        <div class="input">
            <el-switch
                v-model="enableQuickView"
                class="enable-addonify-quick-view"
                size="large"
                inline-prompt
                :active-icon="Check"
                :inactive-icon="Close"
            />
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

**API response:**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "general": {
            "section_label": "General",
            "section_fields": {
                "enable_quick_view": {
                    "label": "Enable Quick View",
                    "description": "",
                    "type": "checkbox",
                    "value": "true"
                },
                "quick_view_btn_position": {
                    "label": "Quick View Button Position",
                    "description": "",
                    "type": "select",
                    "value": "",
                    "choices": {
                        "after_add_to_cart_button": "After Add to Cart Button",
                        "before_add_to_cart_button": "Before Add to Cart Button"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at the App.vue template I am using `{{ options.general.section_label }}` & it is working perfectly. This was a section title & I don't need any reactive state on that.

But, for elements like `checkbox & select` I want them to be reactive so that later I can watch the state changed by user & update it to the API later.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your value to boolean:

```
...
state.options = res.data.settings;
state.enableQuickView = 
  state.options.general.section_fields.enable_quick_view.value === 'true'
...
```

Comment: `state.enableQuickView = state.options.general.section_fields.enable_quick_view.value` yes I did this, even API returns value true. Checkbox does't work like expected.

Comment: @Anuj Subedi hey mate, check my answer again pls

Comment: Thank you @nikola-pavicevic That was the problem ` state.options.general.section_fields.enable_quick_view.value` was returning string 'true' but expected was boolean. I get it! I fixed the API to return boolean instead of a string. :) Cheers